# How to get the parsed json data inside the tableview cell in objective c?

Tags: ios, json, objective-c, xcode, tableview

Here I parsed my json data and kept in **json** and I have to insert into the tableviewcell which is designed custom...here I posted the json parsed code and tableview cell...can somebody please help me with this...

```
NSString *urlstring =@"https://bsedemo.com/instasocial/api/post/feeds?user_id=402&&access_token=$2y$10$TWX2Ym1gM4NBjGCNzTydzuQTZWPcK2tMVw1eWdWvYDFmO4CsKc1kC&&page_no=1&&feed_type=3&&feed_id=&&member_id=402";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlstring];
[[NSURLSession.sharedSession dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error)
    {
        NSError *err;
        NSDictionary * jsondata  = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
        NSMutableArray *json =[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[jsondata objectForKey:@"result"],nil];
        if(err)
        {
            NSLog(@"Failed to load json:%@",err);
            return;
        }
        for (int i=0;i<json.count;i++)
        {
            NSLog(@"json:%@",json[i]);
        }
        for (NSDictionary *dict in json) {
            self->user_image = [dict valueForKey:@"user_image"];
            self->username = [dict valueForKey:@"user_name"];
            self->created_at =[dict valueForKey:@"created_at"];
            self->post_text = [dict valueForKey:@"post_text"];
            self->post_comment_count = [dict valueForKey:@"post_comment_count"];
            self->post_like_count = [dict valueForKey:@"post_like_count"];
            //self->media_img = dict[@"media"][0][@"media_image"];
        }
}]resume];
[self->tableview reloadData];
```

Here I posted the tableview and tableviewcell code which I tried...if I done wrong please correct the code...Thanks in advance!!

```
     - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 10;//name.count;
}

- (nonnull UITableViewCell *)tableView:(nonnull UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Cell";
    TableViewCellVC *cell = [[TableViewCellVC alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    /*TableViewCellVC *cell = (TableViewCellVC *)*/
    
    cell=[tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil)
        {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableViewCellVC" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }
    cell.profileImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"girl1.jpg"]; //[UIImage imageNamed:[user_image objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 23.5;
    //cell.profileImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    //[cell.usernameLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Raleway-Thin" size:15]];
    cell.usernameLabel.text =[name objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];//[username objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //[cell.lastseenLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Raleway-Thin" size:12]];
    cell.lastseenLabel.text = @"Today at 23:52";//[created_at objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //[cell.discriptionLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Raleway-Thin" size:10]];
    cell.discriptionLabel.text =@"All our dreams can come true, if we have the courage to pursue them. – Walt Disney. All our dreams can come true, if we have the courage to pursue them. – Walt Disney.";//[post_text objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.postImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"postpic.jpg"];
    
    //media_img[indexPath.row];
   // [cell.likeLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:[NSString fontAwesomeIconStringForEnum:FAHeart] size:16]];
    cell.likeLabel.text =[NSString fontAwesomeIconStringForEnum:FAHeart];
    //[post_like_count objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.commentLabel.text =[NSString fontAwesomeIconStringForEnum:FAComment]; //[post_comment_count objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.shareLabel.text=[NSString fontAwesomeIconStringForEnum:FAShare];
    cell.moreLabel.text=[NSString fontAwesomeIconStringForEnum:FADotCircleO];
    return cell;
}

    -(void)tableView
{
    tableview = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,topbar.frame.origin.y+topbar.frame.size.height,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height-150) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    tableview.delegate = self;
    tableview.dataSource = self;
    //tableview.rowHeight=UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    //tableview.estimatedRowHeight=400;
    tableview.separatorColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [tableview registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"TableViewCellVC" bundle:nil]
    forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    [mainview addSubview:tableview];
}
```

Comment: At least reload the table inside the block on the main thread. What are you going to accomplish? The value for key `result` is an array but in the loop you are overwriting the `self->…` properties in each iteration. I recommend to create a custom class for the.model.

Comment: @vadian self->user_image is an array and following objects are also mutable array objects..I need to accomplish "to parse the json data and put it inside the tableview cell"..can you please help me..

Comment: `reloadData` should be called inside the closure. Once you get the URL Request response.

Comment: If `self->user_image` was an array it makes no difference. It will contain one object, the data of the last iteration of the loop. How are the `self->...` properties declared?